# Scale svg to whole width

Tags: html, svg

I want to scale my svg so that the width is as big as possible.
I tried this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Laag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" 
     width="345px" height="524px" viewBox="0 0 345 524" enable-background="new 0 0 345 524" xml:space="preserve">
```

And my html is:

```
<object width="100%" data="pdftosvg.svg"></object>
```

But it doesn't work in chrome. I can make the width smaller than this. If I set width="50px" it becomes small. But even if I set width="2000px" it doesn't get as big as I want.

Here is my webpage: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/Test/index.html

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<object>` use `<img>`

```
<img width="100%" src="pdftosvg.svg"></img>
```

This should scale it. You can also set the width to 2000px.

Here is the browser support for svgs in img tag: http://caniuse.com/svg-img

Comment: This article does a nice job discussing fluid image techniques: http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design